# How do I implement a single skip connection?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I don't mean a skip connection for a whole layer to another whole layer, I mean a single connection for a single neuron in some layer L1 to another neuron in some layer L2.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you can just select corresponding tensor channel. Starting from classic ResNet,
https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/a9a8220e0bcb4ce66a733f8c03a1c2f6c68d22cb/torchvision/models/resnet.py#L56-L72

```
def forward(self, x):
    identity = x

    out = self.conv1(x)
    ...
    
    if self.downsample is not None:
        identity = self.downsample(x)

    out += identity
    ...
```

It shall change to

```
    # NCHW layout assumed
    out[:, C2,:,:] += identity[:, C1,:,:]
```

Here C2 is the index of desired target channel (neuron), C1 - source one.